# Where is copy constructor getting called?

Tags: c++, g++, copy-constructor

I wrote a small snippet of C++ code in a main.cpp file and am trying to understand how it's working.

First I defined a class "Value":

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Value {

  int v;

 public:

  Value(int v): v(v) {
    cout << "Ctor called" << endl;
  }

  Value(const Value &rhs): v(rhs.v) {
    cout << "Copy Ctor called. V = " << v << endl;
  }

  Value& operator =(const Value &rhs) {
    cout << "Assignment called" << endl;
    if (this != &rhs) {
      auto tmp = Value(rhs);
      swap(v, tmp.v);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  int rawValue() const {
    return v;
  }

};
```

Then I executed main:

```
Value doubleValue(const Value &v) {
  auto newValue = Value(v.rawValue() * 2);
  return newValue;
}

int main() {
  cout << "Creating v = 10" << endl;
  auto v = Value(10);

  cout << "Creating v = 20" << endl;
  auto v2 = doubleValue(v);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ as my compiler and when I run the following code:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o main.exe
./main.exe
```

Which prints the following:

```
Creating v = 10
Ctor called
Creating v = 20
Ctor called
```

I compile the code again, but without the copy constructors getting optimized out:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o main.exe
./main.exe
```

And now, it print the following:

```
Creating v = 10
Ctor called
Copy Ctor called. V = 10
Creating v = 20
Ctor called
Copy Ctor called. V = 20
Copy Ctor called. V = 20
Copy Ctor called. V = 20
```

Not sure why it's calling the copy constructor so many times. I'm a C++ noob and would like to understand the flow much better. I'm curious to know how this code is running and why the copy constructor is getting called so often.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the copies:

- `auto v = Value(10);` initializes `v` using copy-constructor from `Value(10)`.
- `auto newValue = Value(v.rawValue() * 2);` initializes `newValue` using copy-constructor from `Value(v.rawValue()*2)`.
- `return newValue;` initializes the *return value* using copy-constructor from `newValue`.
- `auto v2 = doubleValue(v);` initializes `v2` using copy-constructor from the *return value*.

All of these are copy-elision contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Return value optimization (RVO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). If RVO is off then your copy constructor is getting called very often. If RVO is on then, for example, the code `auto v = Value(10);` omits copy ctor calls.